# Issue reading lists from Sharepoint listdata.svc from another REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api

all.

I have created a REST ApiController that, among other things, attempts to call the  /_vti_bin/listdata.svc of a Sharepoint site to get the contents of one or more Sharepoint lists.

The ApiController's web.config uses Windows authentication with no impersonation. In the code, I am using System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials for the DataContext.Credentials.

When I run the service locally using Visual Studio, the ApiController is able to call the listdata.svc without any issue and is able to retrieve the full contents of the list(s).

However, when I deploy the ApiController to an actual IIS server that is running under a system account, the call to listdata.svc doesn't retrieve any results. From what I can see in my ApiController's logging, there are no exception beings thrown. According to the logs, the list(s) just appear empty (0 items).

I have checked to make sure the IIS system account has proper access to the Sharepoint site.

Any ideas about why the difference in behavior?

Comment: Try running the application pool as any account other than system.  I can't be certain about IIS, but in Windows the System account often blocks any attempt  to elevate an operation that would run as a domain user.  Network Service should work fine for this.  This may not be the issue but its easy to check, maybe you can share a tad bit of the source code if its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. And the issue is kind of embarrassing considering the fact that I was a SharePoint Site Admin at one time.

I had forgotten that with SharePoint it is possible to have both site *and list* permissions for a given site that do not inherit from one another.

For whatever reason, this site had a set of permissions for the list I was trying to access that were different from the site in general.

The system account (s) used had site permissions of Full Control. But for the list in question, they had no permissions (but other accounts, like my own, did). This would explain why the system accounts could connect to the site's list service but the list appears empty.

After giving the system account (s) read permissions to the list, everything worked.

Lession here is: Just because an account has site permissions doesn't mean it applies to all lists in the site if the admin decides to permission the lists separately.

Hopefully, all of the above make sense.